# Child nodes in excel form treeview come on same level as parent

Tags: excel, forms, treeview, nodes

I hope someone can help me, because I have been stuck on it for days.

I have a worksheet which I want to visualise in a treeview. 
Because this is my first question and my reputation isn't high enough, images are provided in a link.
[img of Worksheet to visualise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJHIF.png)

```
'i:loop through objects
'j:loop through object childs
'counter: keep track of how many childs processed

For i = 1 To 5
Set parentCell = rng.Offset(counter, 0) 'parent values
strParent = parentCell.Value 'parent values

' Build the treeview for both the Left and the right side of the screen
trvLeft.Nodes.Add Key:=strParent, Text:=strParent
trvRight.Nodes.Add Key:=strParent, Text:=strParent


For j = 1 To HelperMethods.AmountInEntity   'can be any number
    strPresent = rng.Offset(counter, 6).Value   '"x" or ""

'Add to left treeview
    Call trvLeft.Nodes.Add(Relative:=strParent, Relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=rng.Offset(counter, 4).Value, Text:=rng.Offset(counter, 4).Value) 

'add to right treeview. If not present, mark as red.
    If strPresent = "x" The
        Call trvRight.Nodes.Add(Relative:=strParent, Relationship:=tvwChild, Key:=rng.Offset(counter, 5).Value, Text:=rng.Offset(counter, 5).Value) 
    Else
        With trvRight.Nodes.Add(strParent, tvwChild, rng.Offset(counter, 5).Value, rng.Offset(counter, 5).Value)
                .ForeColor = vbRed
        End With
    End If

    counter = counter + 1

Next j
Next i
```

Something goes wrong in adding the node to its parent, as all nodes are created on the same level.

One strange thing I have noticed, is that parents are added to the bottom of the list, while children are added to the top. 
[img of flat tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr2Br.png)

Thanks in advance,

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the treeviews, and made new ones. Don't ask me how, but now it works. The wonders of Microsoft Excel...

-edit-

The error occurred again, so it was no isolated event. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this behaviour?